# How to match input according to the order of regular expressions instead of longest length match?

Tags: regex, flex-lexer, lex

I am a new FLEX learner. I want to write a `Scanner1.l` file for the following pattern and action.

My program is taking the longest match every time while taking input.

But I want to parse the input file in a way that it would go through regular expressions one by one and work for the first match occurrence.

How to solve this problem?

```
Pattern                         Action
Blank Space, tab Space          Do nothing
New line                        Count number of line
C identifier                    Print ID
if/else/switch/case/while/for   Print KEYWORD
Any integer number              Print INTEGER
Any float/double number         Print DOUBLE
Any operator                    Print OPERATOR
Anything else                   Print NOT_RECOGNIZED
```

#### Scanner1.l file:

```
%{
    /* comments */
    #define ECHO fwrite(yytext, yyleng,1,yyout);
    int yylineno = 0;
%}
keyword (if|else|switch|case|while|for)
letter_ [a-zA-Z_]
digit [0-9]
digits {digit}+
id {letter_}({letter_}|{digit})*
integer {digits}
operator (\+\+|--|\+|-|>>|<<|\*|\/|%|==|!=|>|<|>=|<=|&&|!|\|\||~|\^|&|\||\+=|-=|\/=|%=|<<=|>>=|&=|\|=|\^=)
float {digits}((.{digits})|((.{digits})((E|e)[+-]?{digits}))|((E|e)[+-]?{digits}))
spacetab [\t ]+
%option noyywrap
%%
{spacetab} { ECHO;/* do nothing */}
\n {yylineno++; ECHO; }
{keyword} {fprintf(yyout,"KEYWORD ");}
{id} { fprintf(yyout,"ID ");}
{float} { fprintf(yyout,"DOUBLE ");}
{integer} {fprintf(yyout,"INTEGER ");}
{operator} { fprintf(yyout,"OPERATOR ");}
(.*{spacetab}) { fprintf(yyout,"NOT_RECOGNIGED ");}
%%
int main(){
    yyin = fopen("Input1.txt","r");
    yyout = fopen("Output1.txt","w");
    yylex();
    fprintf(yyout, "%d\n", yylineno);
    fclose(yyin);
    fclose(yyout);
    return 0;
}
```

#### Input1.txt:

```
^= !=   === == 100.0 100E54 100e+23
0e-90 0 0.9003430000
54.87 77e98 if
if while __ _ _007  wow
```

#### Output1.txt:

```
NOT_RECOGNIGED DOUBLE 
NOT_RECOGNIGED DOUBLE 
NOT_RECOGNIGED KEYWORD 
NOT_RECOGNIGED ID 
4
```

#### Expected Output1.txt:

```
OPERATOR OPERATOR OPERATOR OPERATOR DOUBLE DOUBLE DOUBLE 
DOUBLE INTEGER DOUBLE 
DOUBLE DOUBLE KEYWORD 
KEYWORD KEYWORD ID ID ID  ID
```

I am compiling the program by the following commands in Windows 10:

```
flex Scanner1.l
mingw32-gcc -c lex.yy.c -o Scanner1.yy.o
mingw32-g++ -o Scanner1.yy.exe Scanner1.yy.o
Scanner1.yy
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, the problem is, that FLEX will always try to match the longes match. It means, that if the text matched by your last rule will be the longest one it'll go. If there are two matches with the same length, it will match the rule that is earlier in the code.

For this reason, you should replace

```
.*{spacetab}
```

with

```
.
```

Then, it will be always last to check.

**EDIT**

According to your desired output you also miss "===" in your operators.

**EDIT2**
The last issue was the fact, that in float definition

```
float {digits}((.{digits})|((.{digits})((E|e)[+-]?{digits}))|((E|e)[+-]?{digits}))
```

dot is interpreted as any sign. By replacing it with "." we solved the last problem.

Comment: But why it is not getting the second line properly?

Comment: Give me one minute for debugging.

Comment: The reason is the moment, where you define double. You should replace each . with "." in float {digits}((.{digits})|((.{digits})((E|e)[+-]?{digits}))|((E|e)[+-]?{digits}))

Comment: and I want to take until next new line or tab or space as not recognized.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/93997/discussion-between-xenteros-and-manetsus).